# swift pushViewController memory

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, swift

I'm using the following code to push a new view controller into the stack, the `ViewController` is initalised with an nib and only contains a `webview`, the class is completely empty.

```
    var profileVC = GenericWebViewController()
    profileVC.initWithURL(url)
    navigationController.pushViewController(profileVC, animated:true)
```

When the view is pushed, memory usage goes up, however, when the back button is pressed, the memory level does not go down.

What should I do to get `profileVC` garbage collected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing ;)

Automatic reference counting automatically handles this for you

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Edit: The memory may not be going down for other reasons. Check you don't have any [strong reference cycles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html). To be 100% sure your GenericWebViewController is being cleared from memory, override its dealloc method and make sure it's being called.

Also check out the [leaks instrument](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/conceptual/instrumentsuserguide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html)

Comment: why does the memory usage not go down then?

Comment: @gibo I added some more info with a few possibilities on what could be happening. Of course the web view could be allocating a bunch of create-once-memory out your control